# How insert an NSInteger into a NSMutableArray?

Tags: c++, objective-c, class, vector, nsmutablearray

I'm having trouble converting this C++ source code into a Objective C. I have a class thats suppose to inserts a new line number into  a word list, if the line number is already on then it just returns, in my C++ code i used the vector method insert to insert the line into the lineNumbers Array, but I can't seem to have a substitute for objective c. This is my C++ code

```
/*Constructor. */
UniqueWord::UniqueWord(const string word, const int line)
{
wordCatalog=word;
count = 0;
addLine(line);
}

//Deconstructor.
UniqueWord::~UniqueWord(void)
{
}


/* Adds a line number to the word's list, in sorted order.
   If the number already exists, it is not added again.
*/
void UniqueWord::addLine(const int line){
    int index = newIndex(line);
    ++count;
    if (index == -1)
    return;
    LineNumbers.insert(LineNumbers.begin() + index, line);//here i'm trying to figure out my substitute
}
```

and this is is what I got so far in Objective C:

```
@implementation UniqueWord

-(id)initWithString:(NSString*)str andline:(NSInteger)line{
_wordCatalog=str;
count=0;
//i could not find a substitute for addline(line) here
//what do i return as an id by the way?

}
-(void) addLine:(const int)line{
int index=newIndex(line);
++count;
if(index==-1)
    return;
 [ _LineNumbers //I dont' know what to add here
}
```

Comment: Is that really your `init` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[mutableArray addObject:@(integer)];
```

actually this code wraps the NSInteger (which is an int) into a NSNumber object that can be inserted into a NSMutableArray. Before using the integer to do calculations you may unwrap it by using `[int integerValue]`.

Comment: Surely `insertObjectAtIndex` is closer?

Comment: @trojanfoe it asks for an id for the insertobjectAtIndex

Comment: @OPJ No, it asks for an index, and is similar to the approach you took with `vector`.  You will need to ensure `index < array.count` however.  I have the feeling that this data structure is wrong anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C arrays, both `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray` manage ordered collections of **objects**. Thus you cannot add a primitive type into an array directly. Instead, what you need to do is wrap your primitives and make them objects. For numbers, you'll want to use `NSNumber`. `NSNumber` defines a set of methods specifically for setting and accessing the value as a signed or unsigned char, short int, int, long int, long long int, float, or double or as a BOOL.

So to store an integer into an `NSArray` you would want to wrap it like so `[NSNumber numberWithInt:yourInt]` Then when you want to pull the number out of that you would ask for it's `intValue`

The answer Fr4ncis provided is also correct, it is just a shorthand way of doing it.

Comment: can you explain to me what i'm doing wrong with the constructor?

Comment: Are you referring to your `init` method?

Comment: yes the -(id)initWithString:(NSString*)str andline:(NSInteger)line{
_wordCatalog=str;
count=0;
//i could not find a substitute for addline(line) here
//what do i return as an id by the way?

}

Comment: For help with that id recommend creating a new question. The original question has been answered. Be sure to accept an answer before creating another.